# Disable Shift + right-click in firefox while using an applet

Tags: firefox, right-click, shift

I am working on a site that uses a fairly advanced applet that binds the mouse and keyboard to it so nothing is supposed to affect the browser until you hit esc key. to get back to the site. It is all working fine but:

**if i hit shift + right-click, it will bring up context menu for the browser is there any way to stop that?** normal right-click is disabled just fine and other browsers work fine too, just firefox messing up with the shift+rmb.

ive spent hours on google and havent even found out what exactly is that function (i guess its an extra usability feature for those pesky sites disabling right click, but in this case, it is just getting in the way)